# Websocket between python server and javascript client

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, ubuntu-16.04

I am very new to web development, so any tips regarding the following matter will be useful!
So, the client written in javascript is supposed to communicate with the server written in python. I am trying to establish websocket connection between two PCs running UBUNTU and Windows OS
They work perfectly fine when I run them using UBUNTU, using localhost.
Also, everything works fine when the server is in UBUNTU and the client is in Windows.
Only when the server is located in Windows and the client is in UBUNTU I keep running into the same error.
'Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I tried turning off the firewall settings in Windows, but it didn't work.

Any input will be very appreciated!

## Python Server

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

## Javascript Client

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1337/");

ws.onopen = function(){
    console.log("Connection is Established");
    ws.send("Message to Send");
};

ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    console.log(received_msg);
};
```

Comment: Did you try clearing cookies? Just an idea

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that didn't work. 
I think it might have something to do with how UBUNTU handles outgoing websockets. I ran the server code from a raspberry PI, and UBUNTU client still couldn't connect.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found what was wrong.
Completely forgot that I had to change my router settings for port forwarding.

Comment: As I remember, using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" when starting the python server would also be required for connection between remote PCs

Comment: @AlexPredescu `127.0.0.1` won't work between remote PCs either.